# When base is open, is the base-emitter junction reverse biased? How does leakage current from collector to emitter flow?

Tags: bjt, phototransistor

I've been studying photo transistors, but I'm rusty on leakage current in bjt.
I don't get why CE leakage current is \$ 1+\beta \$ times CB leakage current.
It seems like the bjt amplifies CB leakage current. I have two questions troubling me:

1. How can a thermally generated electron-hole pair in CB junction contribute to a current from the supply? Won't the BE junction stop it?(Because the charge carriers have to cross two reverse biased junctions)
2. The leakage current relation \$I_{CEO} = (1+\beta)I_{CBO}\$ seems to suggest that the common emitter configuration amplifies the leakage current from collector to base(\$CB\$). How can leakage current from collector to base be amplified to produce a huge leakage current from collector to emitter?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8eroT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Search “what is the Early Effect”

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75  it is base width modulation due to change in collector supply. Is Early effect  responsible for the amplification in CB leakage current: \$I_{CEO} = (1+\beta)I_{CBO}\$ ?

Comment: *It seems like the bjt amplifies CB leakage current.* It does. The CB leakage current is the current flowing into the base. As long as the transistor is in active mode (BE in forward, BC in reverse with enough reverse voltage), which it is (in active mode). Then Ib is amplified.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I can understand if base supply is present, the bjt amplifies the base current. But `CB leakage current` is not base current, it is flowing from collector supply into the base. This is different from the base current right?

Comment: In phototransistor the base is open and the bjt amplifies CB leakage current as you said. But I don't get this, how bjt treats CB leakage current SAME as the base current from base supply..

Comment: When base supply is present to forward bias the BE junction, the emitter injects electrons into the base and collector current will be \$\alpha I_E\$. However when the base is open, how can emitter inject electrons into the base? How can CB leakage current get amplified?

Comment: *..it is flowing from collector supply into the base. This is different from the base current right?* I do not see any difference, it is a current flowing into the base. How would the base "know" if the current is due to CB leakage, charge carriers that are the result of light or someone applying a current to the base? As long as it means carriers are injected into the base, I think it is base current.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I believe(maybe incorrectly) base current isn't responsible for the emitter to inject electrons into the base. It is the base-emitter voltage that is responsible for the emitter to inject electrons into the base and cause amplification. I get you're saying base current causes amplified collector current - I don't see how this happens. Base current is a result of base-emitter voltage, this base-emitter voltage injects electrons into the base and causes \$\alpha I_E\$ as collector current. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Thermally generated holes in the CB junction are drifted into the base due to electric field in the CB junction. How do these holes cause more electrons to be injected from emitter-to-base-to-collector(without having any explicit base emitter voltage in phototransistor) is tripping me off..

Comment: Ordinary transistors tend to have low hFE at typical leakage currents so it’s not that bad at room temperature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the \$I_{CBO}\$ current will flow into a "positive" direction in the collector (electrons current in NPN). Thus, \$I_C = I_{C_F} + I_{CBO}\$ where \$I_{C_F}\$ = "forward current".  But for the base terminal, the \$I_{CBO}\$ current is a "negative current" (holes current) \$I_B = I_{B_F} - I_{CBO} \$

And now after we applied the voltage across the collector and emitter and left the base terminal "open". We "create"  a "voltage gradient" across the BJT's. Thus, there will be some small voltage drop across the B-E junction, say 0.2V. Therefore the B-E junction will be forward-biased. But the base is left open thus:

\$I_{CEO} =\alpha \: I_{CEO} + I_{CBO} \$

And if we "solve" for  \$I_{CEO}\$

We have this:

\$I_{CEO} = \frac{ I_{CBO}}{ 1 - \:\alpha} = (\beta + 1) I_{CBO}\$

Comment: Ah when the base is open, part of the collector supply voltage drops across the BE junction and makes it "slightly" forward biased. This means with base open, there is only ONE reverse biased junction, CB ?

Comment: Yes, only one, CB junction.

Comment: Never thought of this, thank you!

Comment: Might add that Icbo is also called 'collector-base leakage current' due to B-C junction. That leakage will bias the B-E junction slightly to forward conduction. Tying the base to emitter will shunt the leakage around the B-E junction, and so C-E leakage will be less.

Comment: @G36 could you please explain this equation \$I_{CEO} =\color{red}{\alpha \: I_{CEO}} + I_{CBO}\$

Comment: you got that from \$I_c = \alpha I_E + I_{CBO}\$ ?

Comment: But it looks like you understand it well. Because we have a BE junction in forward bias, and some part of emitter electrons (base terminal is open, thus Ie = Ic = Iceo) will "meet" the Icbo current "holes" at the base terminal. So, the rest of the emitter electrons (\$ \alpha \: I_{CEO}\$)  will flow to the collector.  But at the same time, Icbo current "will give back " previously lost electrons.  This is why we have  \$I_{CEO} =\alpha \: I_{CEO} + I_{CBO} \$

Comment: Nice! just to check if i really get this. Say emitter injects \$n\$ electrons into base and  \$k\$ pairs of electron-hole pairs are generated at CB junction due to temperature; then \$k\$ holes recombine with \$k\$ emitter injected electrons.  Thus \$n-k\$ electrons will enter into collector terminal from emitter. \$k\$  thermally generated electrons will contribute to the collector current. Total number of electrons leaving out of collector terminal is then \$n-k +k = n\$.

Comment: It looks like you really get it.